# Can I make images expand with the content div without distorting

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage which I really like. I have to support smaller resolutions like 1020X768. But for those visitors with larger monitors, I would like to make use of the extra space. Like setting a minimum width, but can grow with the screen.

I would like to do something like this but I think the images at the top would make this difficult. Is there any way the images could expand with the content area below without distorting?

This is my webpage:

http://sarahjanetrading.com/js/j/Patient-Summary.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding max-width:100% to the images?

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/

Comment: I had this thought, too, but couldn't figure out a reasonable way to get it to scale the "breadcrumb/arrow-style" images effectively. I wouldn't rule it out altogether but I'd be curious to hear how the technique could solve this particular problem effectively.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done. It's nontrivial to provide ALL of the code advice you will need. Better to take it piece at a time, and ask for specific advice as you run into problems:

1. The layout will need to be "fluid" in general. You will need to use relative units of measurement like ems and/or % to pull it off. Read up on "fluid layouts" to get started.
2. Make the "arrows" extra wide (and possibly extra tall if you want them to grow in height as well), set them to the right and vertically centered within their respective containers, set "overflow:hidden" to those containers, and as the containers grow, they will reveal more of the 'hidden' part of the images, creating the illusion that they are stretching but without distorting the image.

Here's a bit of a halfhearted proof of concept:

http://jsfiddle.net/q2Wdc/2/ [updated with full image samples]

I say halfhearted because I ran into problems I hadn't expected. I'll humbly admit that to do it the way I envisioned, the CSS isn't totally trivial for these reasons:

a) by default, images will stack "on top of" each other in the order they appear in the markup. Just to hammer it out I floated right and reversed the list order.

b) to be truly fluid (not just responsive to media queries) you need to be able to work in relative units. But what about the negative margin to create the overlap? Not only does this need to be set in % as well, but the "shift" can break your fluid alignment if not dealt with. I'm not sure that my approach (-5% compensated by more width %) would work in all situations.

c) All the 'arrows' need to be filled solid. I wanted to do a transparent effect, but of course when two semi-transparent arrows overlap, the intersecting pixels are twice as dark as intended. Whoops!

In any event, I was wrong: it's not as easy as imagined. If anyone wants to take a crack at improving the CSS to make it work properly (Home first, Special last, fill up the parent container) I'd be highly interested in seeing your approach. But for me, I had to cut my losses else I'd be hammering away at code that may never even get looked at. ;-)

The "windows" approach still has merit, and could be easily adapted to media queries whereby you are stepping down at known intervals (layout for 1024, layout for 1280) because you could then set certain units to pixels.

Interesting to attempt it, anyhow!

Comment: it's no longer relevant to use `em` as a width/height measurement for resizing as all modern browsers support zooming in the entire page instead of adjusting the base font size. If you need legacy support for IE6 and beyond, then `em` might be useful.

Comment: That is a popular but false assumption lately, zzzzBov. Usability and layout experts have addressed this particular assumption quite regularly throughout the past year.

Comment: do you have any evidence to back up that statement? I don't feel that I was assuming anything about modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE9) Who are these "usability and layout experts" that you're referencing?

Comment: I'm not interested in a comment debate. Ems are alive and well, and I'm not going to be the one to convince you of that fact. I also suggested %. You need a relative measurement to make a fluid layout, period. Take your pick.

Comment: @Greg Pettit, I never said that `em`s weren't useful, they're very important for relative sizing of fonts and many designs; what I stated was that they're not relevant for `width` and `height` styles specifically for flexible layouts only because modern browsers just zoom the entire page, they no longer increase the font size only. If you're not going to provide any proof to your statements, don't bother making any.

Comment: I don't know that I WOULD use it for layout sizing and I never made that recommendation. I said you will need to use relative measurements for a fluid layout. You have fonts to consider for fluid layouts as well. I would be likely to choose % for layout and ems (even better, rems when support is better!) for fonts. As for "proof for your statements", I'm not sure the onus of evidence was upon me in this case. :-/ I think you simply misunderstood. Read it again; I simply said you need relative units to pull off a fluid layout.

Comment: @GregPettit, I was simply countering your first point (specifically "you will need to use relative units of measurement like **ems** and/or % to pull it off") in that `em`s are no longer relevant for relative resizing.

Comment: So it's just miscommunication, then. Ems are relevant for relative sizing... of your fonts. Some people still use them for gutters, too, creating horizontal rhythm for their typography.

Comment: @Greg, did you check check out the website. The images that I am talking about is the background image for the navigation. I want it to be shown completely in all widths. Did you get me?

Comment: So is your current method appliacable for what I want?

Comment: It's general advice, but yes. It sounded like you don't currently have a fluid layout. So the first step is to develop one. With that fluid layout, you'll have to decide how you want the navigation graphics to behave, but one can assume you'll want them to "grow" in terms of boundaries, but not "scale" (distorting pixels). The containers are a "window" on a larger graphic (background-image). With the point to the right and centered, the effect will be complete. The 'point' of each will have to ACTUALLY overlap the next with transparency, not just appear to.

Comment: So if I were to give you this job to you, to do this for me, how much time would it take and how much would you charge?

Comment: One million dollars! Actually, though, I have no idea what the scope of converting your site to fluid would be. A lot would depend on existing markup and CSS. The "windows" method for nav, though, would be trivial. I'll see if I have time to make a fiddle for it sometime tomorrow.